# Mathjax with Webpack

Tags: requirejs, webpack, mathjax

We are having a large web-app developed for education domain using Backbone.js, Marionette and Requirejs. We are also using Mathjax.
Our app has approximately 400 js files and over 200 html [template] files.
We are frequently seeing error related to Module load time out. 
We are evaluating migrating to Webpack based solution and are particularly interested in multiple entry point based split of component loading without much changing the code.

We are however facing issue with Mathjax. We have specified it cdn location in the webpack.config.js for resolve-alias as

```
"mathjax": "http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML&amp;delayStartupUntil=configured",
```

We are using mathjax in our using require syntax as

```
require(
            [ "mathjax" ],
            function( mathjax ){
                console.log("Mathjax loaded in qa module");
            }
        );
```

Webpack is not able to load mathjax module though. Browsing few site, got to know that it may not be possible to use Mathjax with webpack as of now.

Would like to know what are the alternatives possible? Is it possible to combine webpack with some other option to use mathjax? Or say if we split modules properly as the ones that use mathjax and ones that do not use mathjax, then are there any options which will work?

thanks

Pradeep

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

Does it make sense to use a bundler for cdn scripts? I am not sure.

But you can import MathJax from a local source and override the root property, like:

```
import {} from '/lib/MathJax-2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=default';
```

still with the script tag:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    root: "lib/MathJax-2.7.0",
    extensions: ['mml2jax.js'],
    jax: ['input/MathML','output/HTML-CSS'],
    MathMenu: {showRenderer: false},
    'HTML-CSS': {
      availableFonts: ['TeX'],
      preferredFont: 'TeX',
      imageFont: null
    }
  });
</script>
```

Which is not great but at least MathJax is in the bundle.
There is some discussion on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/UT9qMPPwbzg).